# How to pass form FormData from a view to a controller without using a specific Model?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-binding, form-data

How to pass form data from data a view to a controller without using Model? .. the reason behind that I'm trying to build public bootstrap modal that can be rendered as a partial view and submitted whatever data is included.

I almost did everything but for the final step [fetching the form to the controller] I get this error

> POST https://localhost:44357/Pages/Update 500

and here is my attempt

Modal View

```
@model Modal

<div class="modal fade" id="MessageModel" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="MessageModel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <diav class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.header</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div id="ModelForm" class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="ModalForm" action="@Model.SubmitFormUrl">
                    @Html.Raw(Model.body)
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @switch (@Model.footer)
                {
                    case fotterButtons.OneButton:
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        break;
                    case fotterButtons.TwoButtons:
                        <button type="button" onclick="submitModalForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        break;
                }
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal Model

```
public class Modal
{
    // header section
    public string header { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public fotterButtons footer { get; set; }

    public string SubmitFormUrl { get; set; }
}
public enum fotterButtons
{
    OneButton,
    TwoButtons
}
```

JavaScript to submit Modal

```
function submitModalForm() {
var formElem = document.forms['ModalForm'];
/*var rslt = new FormData(formElem);*/

var page = new FormData(formElem);
//console.log([...page]);
fetch(formElem.getAttribute("action"), {
    method: "POST",
    //mode: 'cors',
    //cache: 'no-cache',
    //credentials: 'same-origin',
    //headers: {
    //    "Content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"
    //},
    body: page
}).catch (function (erro) {
    console.log(erro);
}); 
return false;
};
```

The usage of the Modal in view

```
@{
    ViewData["saveForm"] =
    @"
    <h5 class='currentPage'></h5>
    <input type='hidden' name='Id' id='pageID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='pageHtmlContent' id='pageHtml' />

        <input type='text' name='pageName' class='form-control' />
        <textarea name='pageDescreption' class='form-control' ></textarea>
    ";
}

<partial name="_MessageBox"
            model='new Modal() {
    header = "Updating page content" ,
    body = @ViewData["saveForm"].ToString(),
    footer = fotterButtons.TwoButtons,
    SubmitFormUrl = @Url.Action("Update", "Pages")
};' />
```

The targeted ViewModel to be submitted

```
public class VMPage
{
    public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
    public Page page { get; set; }
}
```

and the source Model of page looks like

```
public class Page
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // for auto increment
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string pageName { get; set; }
    public string pageDescreption { get; set; }
    public string pageHtmlContent { get; set; }

}
```

Finally the controller's action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Update(FormCollection page)
    {

        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        context.Update(page);
        //        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    }
        //    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        //    {
        //       throw;
        //    }
        //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        //}
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Notice: Modal view is strongly typed with Modal, not with Page. I need to use this view by rendering it, using the partial tag helper, anywhere in my application to submit any Model "page as an example".

Another note: when I try to get formdata values it comeback with

```
var page = new FormData(formElem);  
console.log([...page]);
```

> 0: (2) ["Id", "f1d7afc6-14a8-4b85-a1dd-02ec1ae9a1f8"]
> 1: (2) ["pageHtmlContent", ""]
> 2: (2) ["pageName", "fffffffffffffffffff"]
> 3: (2) ["pageDescreption", "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"]

But I'm not sure if reciving formdata is correct using `FormCollection page`

Comment: The error message was not very informative. Does the controller method get hit?

Comment: @RoarS. No when debugging never gets to the controller method.

Comment: @RoarS. I add some extra details to make it more clear

Comment: As far as I know, the Update method's parameter name is page, if you want this auto model binding worked, you should make sure your client send the request with the body is form data and the name should be page.